# How to detect a merge and perform a cleanup action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

This is what I have now:

```
1. Create a feature branch with jenkinsfile in it
2. Commit to your new feature branch and the pipeline kicks off
3. The pipeline deploys the app to a new VM/environment/container/whatever
4. The environment/VM persists after the deploy so you can touch/test it physically
```

Now what I want to happen is when the branch is merged and deleted jenkins cleans up and deletes the VM it created for that branch.

Are there triggers for merge/deletion of a branch?

Comment: Not sure I totally understand the question. This is the sort of thing you typically do via github, gitlab or whatever git hosting service you use (assuming it is git, but similar for other CM). You need a trigger message sent to you to see the code has been merged. I don't think can do without that, but with that should be fairly easy!